# Tinyscrollbar and tab key interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinyscrollbar

How to solve the issue with tab key interaction with tinyscrollbar. When I press tab key to jump to input which is not in view, I get destroyed layout, scroll bars go away, etc. How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

**This is what I have done:** Add a `tabindex` attribute to the element, so that the element can receive focus state from the <kbd>tab</kbd> key or mouse click:

```
<div class="scroll-area" tabindex="1">
   <div class="viewport">
     <div class="overview">
       … CONTENT …
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="scrollbar">
     <span class="track"><span class="thumb"></span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Next, I create this function inside the **TinyScrollbar** plugin to add keyboard support and enable the keyboard navigation on `:focus`:

```
$.fn.tinyscrollbar = function(params) {

    var options = $.extend({}, $.tiny.scrollbar.options, params),
        $this = this;

    $this.each(function() {

        $(this).data('tsb', new Scrollbar($(this), options));

        // Enable keyboard support on focus
        $this.on('focus', function () {
            $(this).on('keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 37) {
                    $(this).tinyscrollbar_keystep(40); // step 40px on single keypress
                    return false;
                } else if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 39) {
                    $(this).tinyscrollbar_keystep(-40); // step -40px on single keypress
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

    });

    return $this;

};
```

Then, create `.tinyscrollbar_keystep()` for updating the scroll step below the `.tinyscrollbar_update()`:

```
    $.fn.tinyscrollbar_update = function(sScroll) {
        return $(this).data('tsb').update(sScroll);
    };

    // Add this functionality for scroll update on keypress (in this case)
    $.fn.tinyscrollbar_keystep = function(sScroll) {
        return $(this).data('tsb').keystep(sScroll);
    };
```

And `.keystep` function after `initialize()`

```
    function initialize() { … }

    this.keystep = function(sScroll) {
        if (oContent.ratio < 1) {
            iScroll -= sScroll;
            iScroll = Math.min((oContent[options.axis] - oViewport[options.axis]), Math.max(0, iScroll));
            oThumb.obj.css(sDirection, iScroll / oScrollbar.ratio);
            oContent.obj.css(sDirection, - iScroll);
        }
    };
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/zaqogidexese/1/edit

Comment: It looks fine, but I already implement my workaround by attaching keydown event to inputs, checking if pressed key is tab key, and getting their relative position from element that holds my scrollable area, and calling tyniscrollbar update with recalculated position.

Comment: where is the keystep function? I get a js error because .keystep(sScroll) doesn't exist

Comment: Updated. Check the demo page.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation here and this is my solution for form input fields:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) {  
        case 9: // Tab
            if (e.target.localName == 'input') {
                content.tinyscrollbar_update($(e.target).position().top); 
            }
        break;
    }
});
```

if you have any wrapper element for each input, update the ".position().top" to ".parent().position().top"